# Eclipse won't show Android wysiwyg xml editor

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, editor, wysiwyg

How can I force Eclipse to show my visual XML files. This has happened before, and it usually has something to do with having files edited on another user's machine. The current problem occurred after merging a project from a git repository.

before I get canned responses:
1) the XML files still open up in the Android XML editor by default
2) right clicking the XML file and going to Open With Android XML does not make it miraculously work

the Android XML editor just shows a blank grey canvas. I can get to the XML but I am editing blind here

It is just this project's files that won't display

solutions?

Comment: Can you clarify what's happening and what should be happening instead?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something happened during merge.
Try to open those Android xml files in some 3d-party xml editor.
Or validate them here: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: `No errors were found` from xmlvalidation.com , I can read the XML and nothing is changed, unless there are possibly hidden characters that mess up Android's editor

Comment: How did you validate XML? Copy-pasted or uploaded the file? Upload the file to validator.

Comment: Can you share your xml anywhere?

Comment: No, I can do a file comparison between git revisions and see the file  text is exactly the same. An XML parser shouldnt have trouble. Are there any real solutions floating around? This isn't the first time I've seen the android xml editor in eclipse act strange.

Comment: Well, try to re-install ADT plugin

Comment: I might try that. One thing that got me close was changing the 'theme' in the visual editor, it will then show me my buttons and stuff. but then the visual editor says it cant find any of my drawables (despite the project not complaining, nor the textual xml editor, nor the app)

Answer (score 0):

I installed an extra package (just a random one from Android SDK manager), it forced ADT or something to update, and my XML layouts were working again.

edit: and this turned out to be a temporary solution. Once closing and reopening Eclipse they cease to show up. Using imac